# Error occurred while launching Selendroid Server

Tags: android-testing, selendroid

I downloaded the jar and tried to launch the selendroid server with the command:

`java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.8.0-with-dependencies.jar -app selendroid-test-app-0.8.0.apk`

But it seems to be giving me this error:

`SEVERE: Error occurred while building server: An error occurred while resigning the app 'selendroid-test-app-0.8.0.apk'`

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and found a list of things required to make selendroid work on Windows:

> Java JDK (minimum 1.6) must be installed and JAVA_HOME configured to point to that JDK 
> (tools like the **jarsigner** should be present in the JDK.)

The Android SDK maynot have all the required tools and you must download specific tools through the android SDK manager:

1. Open the Android SDK Manager window
2. Select the **Tools** checkbox.
3. Select the checkbox for the **latest Android SDK**.
4. From the Extras folder, select the checkbox for the **Android Support Library**.
5. Click the Install packages… button to complete the download and installation.

> ANDROID_HOME variable should point to the SDK:
>   **set ANDROID_HOME=C:\${installation location}\SDK
>
>   set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools**

(This is only for Windows. For other OS you can check this link:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/)

Comment: what do you mean by "4. From the 'extras folder'" ??

Answer (score 2):

Just check the log before this error. I too faced the exact same error and found through the logs that my JAVA_HOME was redirecting to the JRE folder and not Java SDK.

Change your JAVA_HOME variable for JAVA SDK path. For me this resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks,My JAVA_HOME was pointing to the the JDK but there was a problem with my Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25 in windows 64 bit OS and restarting the cmd window helped me resolve the issue.
Also ANDROID_HOME path must be set correctly as said by @LoneChaos

Answer (score -1):

Set the `JAVA_HOME` path and `ANDROID_HOME`Re path

Comment: Please do not use answers for comments and "me too"s.